# Comparison of multi-line strings in Python unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, unicode

When I compare two Unicode strings in a Python unit test, it gives a nice failure message highlighting which lines and characters are different. However, comparing two 8-bit strings just shows the two strings with no highlighting.

How can I get the highlighting for both Unicode and 8-bit strings?

Here is an example unit test that shows both comparisons:

```
import unittest

class TestAssertEqual(unittest.TestCase):
    def testString(self):
        a = 'xax\nzzz'
        b = 'xbx\nzzz'
        self.assertEqual(a, b)

    def testUnicode(self):
        a = u'xax\nzzz'
        b = u'xbx\nzzz'
        self.assertEqual(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The results of this test show the difference:

```
FF
======================================================================
FAIL: testString (__main__.TestAssertEqual)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/data/don/workspace/scratch/scratch.py", line 7, in testString
    self.assertEqual(a, b)
AssertionError: 'xax\nzzz' != 'xbx\nzzz'

======================================================================
FAIL: testUnicode (__main__.TestAssertEqual)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/data/don/workspace/scratch/scratch.py", line 12, in testUnicode
    self.assertEqual(a, b)
AssertionError: u'xax\nzzz' != u'xbx\nzzz'
- xax
?  ^
+ xbx
?  ^
  zzz

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

### Update for Python 3

In Python 3, string literals are Unicode by default, so this is mostly irrelevant. `assertMultiLineEqual()` no longer supports byte strings, so you're pretty much stuck with regular `assertEqual()` unless you're willing to decode the byte strings to Unicode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A little digging in the [Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dd6c8bbfec4a1e09a1f698c06cadbb807ed58b91/Lib/unittest/case.py#L197-L206) shows that `TestCase` registers a bunch of methods to test equality for different types.

```
self.addTypeEqualityFunc(dict, 'assertDictEqual')
self.addTypeEqualityFunc(list, 'assertListEqual')
self.addTypeEqualityFunc(tuple, 'assertTupleEqual')
self.addTypeEqualityFunc(set, 'assertSetEqual')
self.addTypeEqualityFunc(frozenset, 'assertSetEqual')
try:
    self.addTypeEqualityFunc(unicode, 'assertMultiLineEqual')
except NameError:
    # No unicode support in this build
    pass
```

You can see that `unicode` is registered to use `assertMultiLineEqual()`, but `str` is not registered for anything special. I have no idea why `str` is left out, but so far I have been happy with either of the following two methods.

### Call Directly

If an 8-bit string isn't registered to use `assertMultiLineEqual()` by default, you can still call it directly.

```
def testString(self):
    a = 'xax\nzzz'
    b = 'xbx\nzzz'
    self.assertMultiLineEqual(a, b)
```

### Register String Type

You can also register it yourself. Just add an extra line to your test case's `setUp()` method. Do it once, and all your test methods will use the right method to test equality. If your project has a common base class for all test cases, that would be a great place to put it.

```
class TestAssertEqual(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TestAssertEqual, self).setUp()
        self.addTypeEqualityFunc(str, self.assertMultiLineEqual)

    def testString(self):
        a = 'xax\nzzz'
        b = 'xbx\nzzz'
        self.assertEqual(a, b)

    def testUnicode(self):
        a = u'xax\nzzz'
        b = u'xbx\nzzz'
        self.assertEqual(a, b)
```

Either of these methods will include highlighting when the string comparison fails.

Comment: Registering the string type doesn't work for me, but calling the method directly does.

Comment: TLDR : Use assertMultiLineEqual for all.

Comment: Wow. Ridiculously complicated. Is there a pytest variant for this?

Comment: Unless you're stuck using Python 2, @ZephaniahGrunschlag, this shouldn't be an issue anymore. String literals are Unicode by default in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks @DonKirkby. My problem was that I was comparing a multiline `f-string` to a standard multiline string. It was adding a whole bunch of `\n` characters to one and not the other. Then I converted the standard string to an `f-string` and the comparison worked (but I had to but a lint ignore for using an `f-string` without any interpolated variable)

Comment: Sounds like you should ask a separate question, @ZephaniahGrunschlag. F-strings shouldn't change white space behaviour, as far as I know.