# Pass Raised Error in function to Exception Raised by UnitTest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I would like to write a function that raises an error when it fails and then passes that to unittest. Consider the following:

```
class undefinedTerms(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.A = frozenset((1,2,3,2,1,4,2,5,6,3,5,7,1,5,2,4,8))
        self.B = frozenset((1,4,5,6,3,4,2,5,4,3,1,3,4,2,5,3,6,7,4,2,3,1))
        self.C = frozenset((1,2,3,2,1,4,2,5,6,3,5,7,1,5,2,4))
        self.D = (1,2,1)

    def is_a_set(self,set_this):
        try:
            assert isinstance(set_this, (set,frozenset))
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError("The object you passed is not a set.")
        return True

    def test_A_is_a_set(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_a_set(self.A))

    def test_B_is_a_set(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_a_set(self.B))

    def test_C_is_a_set(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_a_set(self.C))

    def test_D_is_a_set(self):
         self.assertTrue(self.is_a_set(self.D), self.is_a_set(self.D))


suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(undefinedTerms)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

This gives the following output.

```
test_A_is_a_set (__main__.undefinedTerms) ... ok
test_B_is_a_set (__main__.undefinedTerms) ... ok
test_C_is_a_set (__main__.undefinedTerms) ... ok
test_D_is_a_set (__main__.undefinedTerms) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_D_is_a_set (__main__.undefinedTerms)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-33-4751f8653e7a>", line 27, in test_D_is_a_set
    self.assertTrue(self.is_a_set(self.D), self.is_a_set(self.D))
  File "<ipython-input-33-4751f8653e7a>", line 12, in is_a_set
    (type(set_this) is set))
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

What I would like is for the `AssertionError` to *be* the `TypeError` defined in the function. I am open to radically different implementations.

### Update

I think I was unclear as to precisely what I am after. After reading comments and answers I believe what I want is to create a custom assertion.

This has previously been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655724/how-to-write-a-custom-assertfoo-method-in-python).

Comment: How about `isinstance(set_this, (set, frozenset))`? And why would you expect `except TypeError` to catch an `AssertionError`? Could you explain what you're actually trying to do, and why?

Comment: Thanks for the cleaned up assert statement. I don't *expect* anything. I am trying to wrap my head around this assertion thing.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement - unless *the expression itself* throws an error (which neither `isinstance` nor `type` will, in this case), you'll always get an `AssertionError` from a failing `assert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`.assertIsInstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIsInstance)

```
def assert_is_set(self, set_this):
        self.assertIsInstance(set_this, (set, frozenset))
```

At this point, you don't really need a function and can just inline the check.

You can also use the more general [`.fail()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.fail) method if your conditions become more complex.

> Signals a test failure unconditionally, with msg or None for the error message

```
if something:
    self.fail("Computer broken!")
```

The documentation page has a [list of all the assertions available](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) in TestCases

Comment: I liked your previous suggestion involving `.fail()`. This is a simplified example of something I am trying to do in general. In general, I will seldom have built-in assertion statements that meet my needs.

Comment: Would you mind reposting that snippet, perhaps as an optional implementation?

Comment: Thanks for your help in thinking about this. I have decided to go with an alternative implementation, but I will continue to think about `.fail()`.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655724/how-to-write-a-custom-assertfoo-method-in-python), I believe what I was after is custom assertion methods. This is the final implementation I went with.

```
class SetAssertions:
    def assertIsASet(self, set_this):
        if not isinstance(set_this, (set,frozenset)):
            raise AssertionError("The object you passed is not a set.")

import unittest

class undefinedTerms(unittest.TestCase, SetAssertions):

   def setUp(self):
       self.A = frozenset((1,2,3,2,1,4,2,5,6,3,5,7,1,5,2,4,8))
       self.B = frozenset((1,4,5,6,3,4,2,5,4,3,1,3,4,2,5,3,6,7,4,2,3,1))
       self.C = frozenset((1,2,3,2,1,4,2,5,6,3,5,7,1,5,2,4))
       self.D = (1,2,1)

   def test_A_is_a_set(self):
        self.assertIsASet(self.A)

   def test_B_is_a_set(self):
        self.assertIsASet(self.B)

   def test_C_is_a_set(self):
        self.assertIsASet(self.C)

   def test_D_is_a_set(self):
        self.assertIsASet(self.D)


suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(undefinedTerms)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite) 

test_A_is_a_set (__main__.undefinedTerms) ... ok
test_B_is_a_set (__main__.undefinedTerms) ... ok
test_C_is_a_set (__main__.undefinedTerms) ... ok
test_D_is_a_set (__main__.undefinedTerms) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_D_is_a_set (__main__.undefinedTerms)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-39-495718fb2bad>", line 32, in test_D_is_a_set
    self.assertIsASet(self.D)
  File "<ipython-input-39-495718fb2bad>", line 6, in assertIsASet
    raise AssertionError("The object you passed is not a set.")
AssertionError: The object you passed is not a set.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```