# Soft Asserts in unittest python

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, assert

Currently I have a test case that loops through a dictionary of dictionaries, each of these containing a separate value that I want to test on a web page (I am using Selenium Webdriver, though that is not necessarily relevant to the question). This test case essentially will check that all possible purchase paths for a product are working correctly, which comes out to be about 200 different paths. I want to keep the code simple and not make a test for each one. Below is an example of what I have done to shorten the code:

```
self.templates = {"sales": self.sales", ...)
self.template_keys = ["sales",....]
self.sales - {"locator1": "<locataor info>, ...)
.... <more dictionaries>

for key in self.template_keys:
    for template in self.templates[key]:
        <do purchase path in selenium webdriver>
        assert end_url == expected_end_url # Would like failure to not end test
```

My question is how to get the assert in the nested for loop to not fatally fail and move on to the next step. I have [read this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732827/continuing-in-pythons-unittest-when-an-assertion-fails) and it pretty much seems like he decided to do his own thing without giving any information on what he did. I know that this is an anti-pattern, but it is not worth my time to write all of them out separately. I am wondering if anyone has a good solution, something that works [like soft asserts in Groovy](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/06/25/groovy-closures-make-unit-testing-with-soft-asserts-simple/).

Comment: try using [`assertEqual()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual)

Comment: The idea is to register a failure but keep going, so you see the other failures too, right?

Comment: Will this keep the assert from stopping the test when failed?

Comment: assertEqual() will fail the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just catch the exception:

```
for key in self.template_keys:
    for template in self.templates[key]:
        <do purchase path in selenium webdriver>
        try: assert end_url == expected_end_url # Would like failure to not end test
        except AssertionError: // do something.
```

Comment: This makes the most sense, I was wondering if there was anything else people have done. I guess not.

Comment: This is a Selenium-specific answer to a more generic question. Most people using Python's unittest are not using Selenium.

Answer (score 5):

**Collect a report** of multiple failures:
Replace the `assert` by an `if` and create a descriptor for each failure in its body.
Collect these descriptors in a list (initially empty: `failures = []`):

```
if end_url != expected_end_url:
    failures.append(end_url + ' != ' + expected_end_url)
```

In the end, `assert` the list is empty and use it as the error message if it is not:

```
assert(failures == [], str(failures))
```

Much more readable than catching exceptions -- and very flexible, too.

Answer (score 3):

Today I have exactly the same desire for soft assertions, something I occasionally used at my last job with Java and TestNG. I'm a little surprised nothing like this is built-in to pytest. But I found there are (at least) two Python libraries for this.

The first is softest: https://pypi.org/project/softest/

The second is Python-Delayed-Assert: https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/python-delayed-assert

I haven't personally used either of them yet, but looking over the examples, it looks like they solve the same problem in essentially the same way.